# Issue fetching primary keys of table in embedded data source H2

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, junit, h2

I am writing a unit test to test the data source behaviour.

I have written test like below

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class HTests {

    private H helper;
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        dataSource = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
                .setName("testDB;MODE=PostgreSQL")
                .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2) //.H2
                .addScript("schema.sql")
                .build();
        helper = new H(dataSource);
    }

    @Test
    void getPkKeys() throws SQLException {
        String primaryKey = helper.pkKeys("links");
        Assertions.assertEquals("ID", primaryKey);
    }
```

The primary key function is written like below inside class `H`

```
@Component
@AllArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class H {

    private final DataSource dataSource;

    public String pkKeys(String table) {
        try(Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection()) {
            DatabaseMetaData db = connection.getMetaData();
            try(ResultSet tableColumns = connection.getMetaData().getPrimaryKeys(null, "public", table)) {
                while (tableColumns.next()) {
                    log.info("Found {}", tableColumns.getString(COLUMN_NAME));
                    return tableColumns.getString(COLUMN_NAME);
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }

        throw new IllegalStateException("primary key is required");
    }
}
```

My `schema.sql` looks like below

```sql
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE
(
    ID int NOT NULL,
    FIRST_NAME varchar(255),
    LAST_NAME varchar(255),
    ADDRESS varchar(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES (1, 'James', 'Gosling', 'Canada');
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES (2, 'Donald', 'Knuth', 'USA');
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES (3, 'Linus', 'Torvalds', 'Finland');
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES (4, 'Dennis', 'Ritchie', 'USA');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS links;

CREATE TABLE links (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    url VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    description VARCHAR (255),
        last_update DATE
);

INSERT INTO links (url, name)
VALUES('https://www.postgresqltutorial.com','PostgreSQL Tutorial');
```

Issue is `primaryKey` function never returns primary keys of above tables.

Error logged is

```
15:46:19.866 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils - Executed SQL script from class path resource [schema.sql] in 11 ms.
15:46:19.867 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource - Creating new JDBC Driver Connection to [jdbc:h2:mem:testDB;MODE=PostgreSQL;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=false]

java.lang.IllegalStateException: primary key is required

    at abc.bcd.sql.H.pkKeys(H.java:40)
```

I have verified via debugger that these tables are created fine and are available in database metadata of connection instance.

Comment: This is a really good example why testing against a different database than used in production doesn't really test anything at all. H2 converts unquoted names to uppercase if I'm not mistaken. try `getPrimaryKeys(null, "PUBLIC", table)`

Comment: I've tried that already and it doesn't give anything also. To be nearly similar as production i've used mode as `PostgreSQL`. thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much it was the issue you mentioned `H2 converts unquoted names to uppercase if I'm not mistaken.`

Comment: `;MODE=PostgreSQL` should normally be used together with `;DATABASE_TO_LOWER=TRUE;DEFAULT_NULL_ORDERING=HIGH`: https://h2database.com/html/features.html#compatibility